# url_paths - problems understanding them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Ok, I sorta (not really) understand url_paths (assuming I'm using the correct terminology here) ...

Let's use edge guides as an example here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

These are some of the paths listed:

```
1. articles_path 

2. new_article_path

3. article_path(@article)

4. edit_article_path(@article)

5. article_path(article)

6. edit_article_path(article)
```

What's the different between 3 & 5, or even 1? Or 4 & 6?

Why is one passing an article object, and the other one isn't? By article object, I meant `@article` in parenthesis.

1, I get, it lists all the articles. 2, I get, it lists the path for new article.

I get the others too, sorta, like edit leads to edit page, but what I don't get is the `(@article)` or even `(article)`. And also, what does even `(article)` pass since it's not even an object instance?

Does that make my confusion clear?

Any explanations would be helpful! Merci!

**edit one**

Ok, to sum up what you're saying so far ...

There's no difference between (@article) & (article). They're both parameters that regardless of whether it's an instance variable, or just the variable that pass on the *same* info to the helper function, ie url_path.

And, the url_path is a helper function.

Is that correct?

Comment: `article` or `@article` is a  parameter of function.  they both represent same thing i.e article object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
3. article_path(@article)

5. article_path(article)
```

There is no difference in above `function`. This function generates path for `show` action. The generated value will look something like this,

```
/article/2
```

There is huge difference between above function and

```
1. articles_path
```

First, it doesn't takes any parameter. It generate path for `index` action. There is also spelling difference. the path will looks something like this. Notice the plural.

```
 /articles
```

Now,

```
 4. edit_article_path(@article)
 6. edit_article_path(article)
```

It generates path for `edit` action. Since, all editing url is unique  that's why you have to pass the parameter. The generated path will look something like

```
/article/5/edit
```

> Why is one passing an article object, and the other one isn't? By article object, I meant @article in parenthesis.

Because for editing, you need something mainly `id` to to edit (`update`) the record. For viewing all records you dont need any key.

> what I don't get is the (@article) or even (article). And also, what does even (article) pass since it's not even an object instance?

The above are just the `helper` functions. You are passing the parameter. It doesn't matter you pass instance variable or just the variable. You can also pass the `id` instead of full object.

The above answer is assuming that you are talking about Restful (`resouces`). Certainly, the above function will change its return value if you customise it .

Comment: wow! thanks for such a through explanation! i've tried summing up what i think you meant. it's in my edit one in my post above. did i understand you correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a term called CRUD.  It stands for create, read, update, delete.  These are the main things you can do to an object.  The things in parentheses are called arguments, and they refer to the specific thing you are trying to change.  Lets say you want users to be able to create, read, update, and/or delete comments.  To list all comments or to make a new comment, you don't need to specify a particular comment.  If you want to edit a comment though, you need to tell rails what comment you want to edit.  The thing in parenthesis tells rails exactly what article you want to edit.

In regards to the difference between article_path(@article) and article_path(article), the only difference you posted is the article that the url points to.  Although there are two urls called article_path, it is not the argument that is making them unique, it is the http request method.  If you type rake routes, you should see something like this:

```
article GET        /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#show
        DELETE     /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#destroy
```

Both of those are project_path, buut if you send the method delete, it will destroy the article.  If you send the method get, it will render the show page of the article.